# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wc_get_orders()

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get my orders via wc_get_orders() from Woocommerce orders. But while trying this, I got the error 'Uncaught error: call to undefined function wc_get_orders()' and I don't know what happened here. My code says the following:

```
if(isset($_GET['inicio']) ){
    $initial_date = $_GET['inicio'];
    $final_date = $_GET['fin'];
    $orders = wc_get_orders(array(
        'limit'=>-1,
        //'type'=> 'shop_order',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'status'=> array( 'wc-processing' ),
        'date_created'=> $initial_date .'...'. $final_date, 
        'return' => 'ids',
    ));/**/
    $fechas="de ".$initial_date." a ".$final_date;
}else{
    $orders = wc_get_orders(array(
        'limit' => 10,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'status'=> array( 'wc-processing' ),
        'return' => 'ids',
    ));   
    $fechas="(ultimos 10)";
}
```

I'm trying to get my orders details via wc_get_orders() from Woocommerce orders.

Additional info: complete code is>>

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$host_name = $wpdb->dbhost;
$database = $wpdb->dbname;
$user_name = $wpdb->dbuser;
$password = $wpdb->dbpassword;
/*conectar bdd WP*/$link = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if ($link->connect_error) {die("Connection failed: ". $link->connect_error);}else{/* echo "Connected successfully";/**/}
/*character set to utf8mb4 */$link->set_charset("utf8mb4");

//*
if(isset($_GET['inicio']) ){
    $initial_date = $_GET['inicio'];
    $final_date = $_GET['fin'];
    $orders = wc_get_orders(array(
        'limit'=>-1,
        //'type'=> 'shop_order',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'status'=> array( 'wc-processing' ),
        'date_created'=> $initial_date .'...'. $final_date, 
        'return' => 'ids',
    ));/**/
    $fechas="de ".$initial_date." a ".$final_date;
}else{
    $orders = wc_get_orders(array(
        'limit' => 10,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'status'=> array( 'wc-processing' ),
        'return' => 'ids',
    ));   
    $fechas="(ultimos 10)";
}
//$meta = "...<pre>".var_dump($orders)."</pre>...";

$meta="";
$pedidos=array();
$productos=array();//hay que guardar pedidos y clientes para hacer esa matriz
//$clientes=array();

// Loop through each WC_Order object
foreach( $orders as $order ){
    $fecha=0;
    $dia=0;
    $planoNumero=0;
    $planoLetra=0;
    $latitud=0;
    $longitud=0;
    $nombre=0;
    $tel=0;
    $direccion=0;
    $barrio=0;
    $monto=0;
    $envio=0;
    $total=0;
    $descuento=0;
    $notas=0;
    $formaPago=0;
    $primera=0;
    $marca=0;
    $precio=1;

    
    $meta.= $order . ' - '; // The order ID

    //https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/
    // Get $order object from order ID  
    $orderid = wc_get_order( $order );

    // Now you have access to (see above)...

    if ( $orderid ) {//verifica
        //$meta.="...<pre>".var_dump($orderid)."</pre>...";   

        //objeto a array, es otra forma de traer datos
        $order2 = json_decode(wc_get_order( $order ),true);
        $meta.= $order2["status"]. ' - '.$order2["total"]." - "; // The order ID

        // Datos del usuario
        $user = $orderid->get_user();
        //$meta.="...<pre>".var_dump($user)."</pre>...";   
        $userid=$user->ID;
        $meta.= $userid." username: ".$user->user_nicename." - ";
        $meta.= "plano numero: ".get_user_meta($userid ,'plano_numero',true)." - ";
        $meta.= "plano letra: ".get_user_meta($userid ,'plano_letra',true)." - ";
        $meta.= "latitud: ".get_user_meta($userid ,'latitud',true)." - ";
        $meta.= "longitud: ".get_user_meta($userid ,'longitud',true)." - ";

        $planoNumero=get_user_meta($userid ,'plano_numero',true);
        $planoLetra=get_user_meta($userid ,'plano_letra',true);
        $latitud=get_user_meta($userid ,'latitud',true);
        $longitud=get_user_meta($userid ,'longitud',true);
        if($planoLetra == ''){
            $primera="SI";
        }else{            
            $primera="NO";
        }
        /**/

        //Datos de la orden
        $meta.= $orderid->billing_entrega." dia entrega - ";
        $meta.= $orderid->get_billing_first_name()." ".$orderid->get_billing_last_name();
        $meta.=$orderid->get_date_created();
        $meta.=$orderid->get_date_modified();
        $meta.=$orderid->get_date_completed();
        $meta.=$orderid->get_date_paid();
        
        $fecha=$order2["date_created"]["date"];
        $dia=$orderid->billing_entrega;
        $nombre=$orderid->get_billing_first_name()." ".$orderid->get_billing_last_name();
        //$clientes[]=$nombre;
        $tel=$order2["billing"]["phone"];
        
        $direccion=$orderid->shipping_first_name." ".$orderid->shipping_last_name.", ".$orderid->shipping_address_1." ".$orderid->shipping_address_2.", ".$orderid->shipping_city.", ".$orderid->shipping_state.", ".$orderid->shipping_postcode." ".$orderid->shipping_country;//sacando como objeto
        //$direccion=$orderid->get_address('shipping');  //la trae como objeto
        $direccion=$order2["shipping"]["first_name"]." ".$order2["shipping"]["last_name"]." / ".$order2["shipping"]["address_1"]." ".$order2["shipping"]["address_2"]." / ".$order2["shipping"]["city"]." / ".$order2["shipping"]["state"]." / ".$order2["shipping"]["postcode"]." ".$order2["shipping"]["country"];//o lo puedes sacar así como array
        
        $monto=$order2["total"]-$order2["shipping_total"];
        $envio=$order2["shipping_total"];
        $total=$order2["total"];
        $descuento=$order2["discount_total"];
        $notas=$order2["customer_note"];
        $formaPago=$order2["payment_method_title"];
        
        //trae el barrio de la tabla segun cp
        $cp=$order2["shipping"]["postcode"];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM 0_cp_jo WHERE cp='".$cp."' LIMIT 1;";
        $ejecutarquery=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($ejecutarquery)>0){
            $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ejecutarquery);
            $barrio=$row['barrio'];
        }else{
            $barrio=$cp." c.p. no encontrado";
        }
        /**/
        
        // Get and Loop Over Order Items
        $meta.= "<br>";
        
        $congelados=0;
        $lacteos=0;
        $huerta=0;        
        foreach ( $orderid->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            //$meta.="...<pre>".var_dump($item)."</pre>...";   
                    
            //Datos producto
            $meta.= $item->get_product_id();
            $meta.= " - ".$item->get_name();
            $meta.= " - ".$item->get_quantity(); 

            $producto=$item->get_name();
            $qty=$item->get_quantity();
            
            //terminos producto, categorias en este caso
            $categorias=array();//se busca con in_array() para hacer tabla por categoria
            $terms = get_the_terms ( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat' );
            //$meta.="...<pre>".var_dump($terms)."</pre>...";            
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $meta.= " - Categoria: ".$term->name;
                $categoria=$term->name;
                $categorias[]=$categoria;

                //almacen es todos los productos disque en orden alfabetico
                if($categoria=="congelados"){$congelados++;}
                if($categoria=="Lácteos"){$lacteos++;}
                if($categoria=="Frutas y Verduras"){$huerta++;} 
            }
            
            //atributos del producto como marca
            $product = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() );
            $marca=$product->get_attribute( 'Marca' );
            //el precio
            $precio=$product->get_price();
            $precio=$orderid->get_item_total( $item );;
            
            $productos[]=array(
                "orden"=>$order,
                "cliente"=>$nombre,
                "producto"=>$producto,
                "qty"=>$qty,
                "precio"=>$precio,
                "marca"=>$marca,
                "categorias"=>$categorias);
            
        $meta.= "<br>";
        }
    }
    $meta.= "<br>";
    $meta.= "<br>";

    //guardamos el pedido como un array para el echo mas adelante con un feach
    $pedidos[]=array(
        "fecha"=>$fecha,
        "dia"=>$dia,
        "orden"=>$order,
        "congelados"=>$congelados,
        "lacteos"=>$lacteos,
        "huerta"=>$huerta,
        "plano_numero"=>$planoNumero,
        "plano_letra"=>$planoLetra,
        "latitud"=>$latitud,
        "longitud"=>$longitud,
        "nombre"=>$nombre,
        "tel"=>$tel,
        "direccion"=>$direccion,
        "barrio"=>$barrio,
        "monto"=>$monto,
        "envio"=>$envio,
        "total"=>$total,
        "descuento"=>$descuento,
        "notas"=>$notas,
        "forma_pago"=>$formaPago,
        "primera"=>$primera);
    //poner productos o clientes en orden alfabetico en el array, mejor clientes hace una diagonal casi
    
    
}

function eliminar_acentos($cadena){
        //Reemplazamos la A y a
        $cadena = str_replace(
        array('Á', 'À', 'Â', 'Ä', 'á', 'à', 'ä', 'â', 'ª'),
        array('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
        $cadena );

        //Reemplazamos la E y e
        $cadena = str_replace(
        array('É', 'È', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'é', 'è', 'ë', 'ê'),
        array('E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e'),
        $cadena );

        //Reemplazamos la I y i
        $cadena = str_replace(
        array('Í', 'Ì', 'Ï', 'Î', 'í', 'ì', 'ï', 'î'),
        array('I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i'),
        $cadena );

        //Reemplazamos la O y o
        $cadena = str_replace(
        array('Ó', 'Ò', 'Ö', 'Ô', 'ó', 'ò', 'ö', 'ô'),
        array('O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'),
        $cadena );

        //Reemplazamos la U y u
        $cadena = str_replace(
        array('Ú', 'Ù', 'Û', 'Ü', 'ú', 'ù', 'ü', 'û'),
        array('U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u'),
        $cadena );

        //Reemplazamos la N, n, C y c
        $cadena = str_replace(
        array('Ñ', 'ñ', 'Ç', 'ç'),
        array('N', 'n', 'C', 'c'),
        $cadena
        );      
        
    //como exportas csv que no haya comas
        $cadena = str_replace(
        array(','),
        array(' '),
        $cadena
        );      

        return $cadena;
}
```

This file is located in /wp-admin/ folder

Comment: WooCommece functions may not be loaded when you call the function `wc_get_orders`. On which hook are you calling this function.?

Comment: The error is referencing `wc_get_order()` but in your code you are calling `wc_get_orders()`. You need to share the full code please.

Comment: Done! I added more info and the complete code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't call your script in the Wordpress environment. So, you need to initialize Wordpress first.
Put this at the beginning of your php file:

```
/* Initialize Wordpress */
define( 'BASE_PATH', find_wordpress_base_path()."/" );
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query, $wp_rewrite, $wp_did_header;
require(BASE_PATH . 'wp-load.php');

function find_wordpress_base_path() {
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
    do {
        //it is possible to check for other files here
        if( file_exists($dir."/wp-config.php") ) {
            return $dir;
        }
    } while( $dir = realpath("$dir/..") );
    return null;
}

/* Restrict access to admin only */
if( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' )) return;

/* Now run your script here ... */
```

I would recommend running your script via a cronjob or putting your script into a shortcode, put the shortcode on a private page and then call that page. Then, you don't need the first part.